# Powershell - Select a specific part of Filename

Tags: string, powershell

I need to run an executable on some .txt files in a directory. The executable requires only a part of the files name.
For example, if `FileName= "Hello_World.txt"`, the executable only works if `FileName= "Hello"`.

So far I have the code to loop the executable through every file, but the problem is it uses the complete name of the file.

```
h $magick = 'path\program.exe'
$path = 'path'
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File -Filter "*.txt")
{
    & $magick "$($file.FullName)" -negate
"$path\test_$($file.Name)"
```

Any ideas on how I could select the first part of the name only?
The actual files are named:

```
J=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]_spins_00.txt
J=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]_spins_01.txt
```

The part to be used is: `J=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`

Any ideas on how I could select the first part of the name only? Counting the strings could work (in this case the first 17 strings).

Comment: The delimiter for the files you're looking for is always `_` or the files can have other delimiters too (like `-`, etc)? Also, note, `$file.FullName` is the absolute path of the file not the file name.

Comment: For one thing, if your file names have square brackets, you should use `-LiteralPath` on Get-ChildItem. You can split the file name like this: `($file,BaseName -split '_')[0]` to get the part left of the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Theo's comment and taking into account reading subtleties I managed to do it. I post the code in case someone happens to be in my shoes someday!

```
$magick = 'pathtoprogram'

$path = 'pathtofolder'
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -File -Filter "*.txt") {
    & $magick "$(($file.BaseName -split '_')[0])" -negate "$path\test_$($file.Name)"
    "$(($file.BaseName -split '_')[0])"
```